# use the value of a cell to point to another cell and get its value

Tags: excel, worksheet-function

I'm currently making a cost analysis on a project and I'm not really skilled in Excel.
Here's my problem.
I have a cell A7 (sheet 1) where the amount of months is calculated.
I have a cell F34 (sheet 1) where the total cost needs to be

The total cost is cost month 1 + cost month 2 + ... + cost month (value cell A7)
I solved this by making a table that has the total summarized cost sorted by month
This is A7 through A126 of sheet: StorageMonthlySheet.

Now I want a formula in cell F34 that does something like this:

=valueofcell StorageMonthlySheet!A [ "valueofcell Sheet1!A7" ]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If i read what your after correctly;

This will return the value from the cell in StorageMonthlySheet's column A with the row number from Sheet1, column A7

```
=INDIRECT("StorageMonthlySheet!A" & INDIRECT("Sheet1!A7", TRUE), TRUE)
```

Comment: this worked, although the , should be a ;  
thank you very much